# How to set different WriteConcern for different conditions on the basis of some MongoAction property?

Tags: spring, mongodb, java-8, spring-data-mongodb

What is the possible way to set different WriteConcern values based on some condition of the MongoAction?
For example, i want if the MongoAction contains some value like "ABD", i want there should be no WriteConcern. And if it contains "PAYMENT", then WriteConcern should be SAFE.
What is the possiblie cases i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above can be done implementing the `WriteConcernResolver` and overriding the resolve method as follows:

```
class MyAppWriteConcernResolver implements WriteConcernResolver {

  @Override
  public WriteConcern resolve(MongoAction action) {

    if (action.getEntityClass().getSimpleName().contains("ADB")) {
      return WriteConcern.NONE;
    } else if (action.getEntityClass().getSimpleName().contains("PAYMENT")) {
      return WriteConcern.SAFE;
    }

    return action.getDefaultWriteConcern();
  }
}
```

The passed in argument, `MongoAction`, is what you use to determine the `WriteConcern` value to be used. `MongoAction` contains the collection name being written to, the `java.lang.Class` of the POJO, the converted `DBObject`, as well as the operation as an enumeration (`MongoActionOperation`: `REMOVE`, `UPDATE´, ´INSERT`, `INSERT_LIST`, `SAVE`) and a few other pieces of contextual information.

Comment: Good one! I guess you could mention that an instance of this then needs to be configured on a `MongoTemplate`.